# Remove columns by position in another file

Tags: r

I have a file that has this structure:

```
df
Myfile_R1     Myfile_RN
Myfile_R2
Myfile_R3
```

Then I have another file with 3 columns: Myfile_R1 Myfile_R2 Myfile_R3. I would like that if in df, Myfile_RN is in the first position, then in the other file, the column Myfile_R1 will be removed. If it is in the second position, then Myfile_R2 will be removed and so son. I have thousands of files to test.

Example:

```
df       
Myfile_R1     Myfile_RN
Myfile_R2
Myfile_R3       



df2      

Myfile_R1      Myfile_R2      Myfile_R3            
.........      .........      .........
.........      .........      .........
.........      .........      .........
```

First desired output (Myfile_R1 disappears because Myfile_RN in df is at first row and is replaced by Myfile_RN):

```
df2      

Myfile_RN      Myfile_R2      Myfile_R3            
.........      .........      .........
.........      .........      .........
.........      .........      .........
```

If Myfile_RN is at the second row in df, then Myfile_R2 in df2 will be replaced by Myfile_RN and finally If Myfile_RN is at the third row in df, then Myfile_R3 in df2 will be replaced by Myfile_RN.

Comment: Your question is not that clear.  Could you post a small reproducible example with expected output

Comment: Agree with @akrun. Need a better explanation please.

Comment: Yes, of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code:
let `df` your `dataframe` and `df1` the new `dataframe`
create a vector of column names like below:

```
col_names <- colnames(df)
```

Now, to check the index of you column name use this:

```
index <- which(col_names=='Myfile_RN')
```

Now you got the index. To remove that column from new `dataframe` try this:

```
df1[,index] <- df[,index]
```

for row-wise operation repeat above example with `rownames()`

If 'Myfile_RN' inside the cell of `dataframe` then, try this:

```
row_index <- which(df=='Myfile_RN',arr.ind=TRUE)[,1] #for accessing row index
df1[row_index,] <- df[row_index,]
```

Let me know if this serves your purpose.